# Postgres - inserting a varchar array via SQL

Tags: arrays, database, postgresql, insert, pg

I want to execute this query.

```
INSERT INTO items (title, description,
start_date,
expiration_date,
type,
quantity,
state,
sold,
cover_photo_file_name,
cover_photo_content_type,
cover_photo_file_size,
instructions)
VALUES
(
    'some_test_value',
    'lorem ipsum',
    '2015-01-01 00:00:00',
    '2015-06-10 00:00:00',
    0,
    19,
    0,
    0,
    'RackMultipart20150317-10093-1ny4gmx.gif',
    'image/gif',
    157574,
    {"lorem ipsum\r","dolor sit\r","loremloremipsumipsum 'sitsit' dolor sit"}
    );
```

I get a very nasty

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "{"
```

When i try to do it the

```
ARRAY["Lorem ipsum\r", ...]
```

I get:

```
ERROR: column "Lorem ipsum" does not exist
```

The problem is i cannot change the db right now (i don't have time for it) so i need to construct a query that will "do" the job (although this db requires normalization with use of DROP DATABSE... )

What is wrong with my code? Maybe i'm missing something obvious but my tired mind is just skipping it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO items (title, description,
start_date,
expiration_date,
type,
quantity,
state,
sold,
cover_photo_file_name,
cover_photo_content_type,
cover_photo_file_size,
instructions)
VALUES
  ('some_test_value',
  'lorem ipsum',
'2015-01-01 00:00:00',
'2015-06-10 00:00:00',
0,
19,
0,
0,
'RackMultipart20150317-10093-1ny4gmx.gif',
'image/gif',
157574,
'{"lorem ipsum\r","dolor sit\r","loremloremipsumipsum 'sitsit' dolor sit"}'
);
```

Please try this...

Comment: Please can you also add what did you change?

Comment: While this is correct, I encourage you to try to explain *why* and/or add relevant documentation links.

Answer (score 6):

String literals need to be enclosed in single quotes `'` not double quotes.

Only inside the "short hand" array notation using `{...}` the values need to be enclosed in double quotes:

```
'{"lorem ipsum", "dolor sit"}'::text[]
```

Using the `ARRAY` constructor is easier here:

```
ARRAY['Lorem ipsum\r', ...]
```

because the single quotes don't need to be escaped.

Comment: The first is actually different, the single quotes form part of the actual value of the array member. Compare `SELECT '{''lorem ipsum'', ''dolor sit''}'::text[];` with `SELECT '{"lorem ipsum", "dolor sit"}'::text[];` or `SELECT '{lorem ipsum, dolor sit}'::text[];`. Array literals use *double quotes* for inner values, and those quotes are optional. It's more like CSV than SQL. Yes, that's horrible.

Comment: @CraigRinger: of course, what was I thinking. Corrected

Comment: I don't mean to follow you around and nitpick by the way. Trying to help out. I've just realised it might seem a bit that way lately ;-)